# Nested MariaDB Query Slow

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-optimization, correlated-subquery

I am having performance issues with a query, I have 21 million records across the table, and 2 of the tables I'm looking in here have 8 million each; individually, they are very quick. But I've done a query that, in my opinion, isn't very good, but it's the only way I know how to do it.

This query takes 65 seconds, I need to get it under 1 second and I think it's possible if I don't have all the SELECT queries, but once again, I am not sure how else to do it with my SQL knowledge.

Database server version is MariaDB 10.6.

```
SELECT
pa.`slug`,
(
    SELECT 
    SUM(`impressions`) 
    FROM `rh_pages_gsc_country` 
    WHERE `page_id` = pa.`page_id` 
    AND `country` = 'aus'
    AND `date_id` IN 
        (
            SELECT `date_id` 
            FROM `rh_pages_gsc_dates` 
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
        )
) as au_impressions,
(
    SELECT 
    SUM(`clicks`) 
    FROM `rh_pages_gsc_country` 
    WHERE `page_id` = pa.`page_id` 
    AND `country` = 'aus'
    AND `date_id` IN 
        (
            SELECT `date_id` 
            FROM `rh_pages_gsc_dates` 
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
        )
) as au_clicks,
(
    SELECT 
    COUNT(`keywords_id`) 
    FROM `rh_pages_gsc_keywords` 
    WHERE `page_id` = pa.`page_id`
    AND `date_id` IN 
        (
            SELECT `date_id` 
            FROM `rh_pages_gsc_dates` 
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
        )
) as keywords,
(
    SELECT 
    AVG(`position`) 
    FROM `rh_pages_gsc_keywords` 
    WHERE `page_id` = pa.`page_id`
    AND `date_id` IN 
        (
            SELECT `date_id` 
            FROM `rh_pages_gsc_dates` 
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
        )
) as avg_pos,
(
    SELECT 
    AVG(`ctr`) 
    FROM `rh_pages_gsc_keywords` 
    WHERE `page_id` = pa.`page_id`
    AND `date_id` IN 
        (
            SELECT `date_id` 
            FROM `rh_pages_gsc_dates` 
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
        )
) as avg_ctr
FROM `rh_pages` pa
WHERE pa.`site_id` = 13
ORDER BY au_impressions DESC, keywords DESC, slug DESC
```

If anyone can help, I don't think the table structure is needed here as it's basically shown in the query, but here is a photo of the constraints and table types.

[image: SQL Tables]

Anyone that can help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `JOIN`?

Comment: If you've seen other query-optimization questions on Stack Overflow, you might have noticed that folks _always_ ask for a few details to help us: (1) usable `CREATE TABLE` statements, so we don't have to guess at your data types, indexes, and constraints, and so we can test it without having to type in the table definitions (i.e. _not_ screenshots). Even better if you can use one of the SQL fiddle sites to post. (2) the EXPLAIN report you are getting currently, (3) the exact version of your database server, which you get with `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: hey @BillKarwin I added a screenshot to the question with the table structure for everyone. I am using Maria DB 10.6.*

Comment: @FanoFN I would normally use a JOIN, but because my experience with sub queries is extremely limited, I couldn't work out even after literally hours of research, how to do it with joins.

Comment: Try this https://dbfiddle.uk/xqHOYfoU . You can use this fiddle to insert your _example_ table structure, sample data and test run it there. Just use fake table names and fake data, don't worry, we don't require exact information of that.

Comment: @FanoFN I can't workout how to add my database to that tool, I did run that query but it says "Column 'impressions' in field list is ambiguous. I found this tool, I stripped the db back, and didn't include my keys and constraints but this is what I have (0 data added) https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n4cYpJjkFpYnqxbz6f6K3j/0

Comment: Ahh ok.. that's cause you have similar column names between those tables and I defined in that join without referencing which table should the column be should it `SELECT`. Here's an update https://dbfiddle.uk/tJyZm62f . When you said you're run the query, do you mean in your database or in that tool?

Comment: @FanoFN That didn't work unfortunately, ends up timing out after about 5 minutes. The issue is with the dates. If you look at the dates table, the dates have an ID and all tables reference that date_id, so for each one I need to do a date id lookup. (see my query). I think this is where the bottle neck is. The query runs fine when I adjust yours to remove the dates.

Comment: Your query consists of many select, run each one of them separately to find out which one takes the longest.

Comment: Actually, upon re-inspecting your `CREATE TABLE` syntax in the fiddle, you don't have any indexes. If that's your exact table structure, then it's more than likely the reason why the query is slow. Here, I've added sample data, alter table to add example indexes and show the `EXPLAIN` difference of the query between your tables without and with indexes https://dbfiddle.uk/8XUj6e5O

Answer (score 1):

Do *NOT* normalize any column that will be regularly used in a "range scan", such as `date`.  The following is terribly slow:

```
  AND  `date_id` IN (
                SELECT  `date_id`
                    FROM  `rh_pages_gsc_dates`
                    WHERE  `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
                                      AND NOW() )
```

It also consumes extra space to have `BIGINT` (8 bytes) pointing to a `DATE` (5 bytes).

Once you move the `date` to the various tables, the subqueries simplify, such as

```
        SELECT  AVG(`position`)
            FROM  `rh_pages_gsc_keywords`
            WHERE  `page_id` = pa.`page_id`
              AND  `date_id` IN (
                SELECT  `date_id`
                    FROM  `rh_pages_gsc_dates`
                    WHERE  `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
                                      AND NOW() )
```

becomes

```
        SELECT  AVG(`position`)
            FROM  `rh_pages_gsc_keywords`
            WHERE  `page_id` = pa.`page_id`
              AND  `date` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
```

I'm assuming that nothing after "NOW" has yet been stored.
If there are dates in the future, then add

```
              AND  `date`  < NOW()
```

Each table will probably need a new index, such as

```
INDEX(page_id, date)  -- in that order
```

(Yes, the "JOIN" suggestion by others is a good one.  It's essentially orthogonal to my suggestions above and below.)

After you have made those changes, if the performance is not good enough, we can discuss [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is aggregating (summarizing) rows from two different detail tables, `rh_pages_gsc_country` and `rh_pages_gsc_keywords`, and doing so for a particular date range. And it has a lot of [correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

The first steps in your path to better performance are

- Converting your correlated subqueries to independent subqueries, then JOINing them.
- Writing one subquery for each detail table, rather than one for each column you need summarized.

You mentioned you've been struggling with this. The concept I hope you learn from this answer is this: you can often refactor away your correlated subqueries if you can come up with independent subqueries that give the same results, and then join them together. If you mention subqueries in your SELECT clause -- `SELECT ... (SELECT whatever) whatever ...`  -- you probably have an opportunity to do this refactoring.

Here goes.  First you need a subquery for your date range. You have this one right, just repeated.

```sql
           SELECT `date_id` 
            FROM `rh_pages_gsc_dates` 
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
```

Next you need a subquery for `rh_pages_gsc_country`. It is a modification of what you have. We'll fetch both SUMs in one subquery.

```sql
      SELECT SUM(`impressions`) impressions,
             SUM(`clicks`) clicks, 
             page_id, date_id
        FROM `rh_pages_gsc_country` 
       WHERE `country` = 'aus'
      GROUP BY page_id, date_id
```

See how this goes? This subquery yields a virtual table with exactly one row for every combination of `page_id` and `date_id`, containing the number of impressions and the number of clicks.

Next, let's join the subqueries together in a main query. This yields some columns of your result set.

```sql
SELECT pa.slug, country.impressions, country.clicks
  FROM rh_pages pa 
  JOIN (
           SELECT SUM(`impressions`) impressions,
                  SUM(`clicks`) clicks, 
                  page_id, date_id
             FROM `rh_pages_gsc_country` 
            WHERE `country` = 'aus'  -- constant for country code
            GROUP BY page_id, date_id
      ) country ON  country.page_id = pa.page_id
  JOIN (
           SELECT `date_id` 
            FROM `rh_pages_gsc_dates` 
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
       ) dates ON dates.date_id = country.date_id
 WHERE pa.site_id = 13             -- constant for page id
 ORDER BY country.impressions DESC
```

This runs through the rows of `rh_pages_gsc_dates` and `rh_pages_gsc_country` *just once* to satisfy your query. So, faster.

Finally let's do the same thing for your `rh_pages_gsc_keywords` table's summary.

```sql
SELECT pa.slug, country.impressions, country.clicks,
       keywords.keywords, keywords.avg_pos, keywords.avg_ctr
  FROM rh_pages pa 
  JOIN (
           SELECT SUM(`impressions`) impressions,
                  SUM(`clicks`) clicks, 
                  page_id, date_id
             FROM `rh_pages_gsc_country` 
            WHERE `country` = 'aus'  -- constant for country code
            GROUP BY page_id, date_id
      ) country ON  country.page_id = pa.page_id
  JOIN (
           SELECT SUM(`keywords_id`) keywords,
                  AVG(`position`) position,
                  AVG(`ctr`) avg_ctr, 
                  page_id, date_id
             FROM `rh_pages_gsc_keywords` 
            GROUP BY page_id, date_id
       ) keywords ON keywords.page_id = pa.page_id
  JOIN (
           SELECT `date_id` 
            FROM `rh_pages_gsc_keywords` 
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
       ) dates ON dates.date_id = country.date_id
              AND dates.date_id = keywords.date_id
 WHERE pa.site_id = 13             -- constant for page id
 ORDER BY impressions DESC, keywords DESC, slug DESC
```

This will almost certainly be faster than what you have now. If it's fast enough, great.  If not, please don't hesitate to ask another question for help, tagging it [query-optimization](/questions/tagged/query-optimization). We will need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) before asking a followup question.

*I did not, repeat not, debug any of this. That's up to you.*